# Interaction between numpy arrays of pyOpenCL vector types and numpy arrays of floats

Tags: numpy, pyopencl

I find it quite convenient to use both structs and np.ndarrays using dtypes like pyopencl.cltypes.float2. This is a clear and self documenting way to pass structured data to my kernels, as opposed to just a bunch of floats.

However I find certain behavior inconvenient. For example given:

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl.cltypes as cltp

a = np.zeros((3,5), dtype=cltp.float2)


>>> a
array([[(0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.)],
       [(0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.)],
       [(0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.)]],
       dtype=[(('x', 's0'), '<f4'), (('y', 's1'), '<f4')])
```

I can construct my data structure piecemeal before passing it to the kernel by doing e.g.

```
a[:,1] = (42,-42)
>>> a
array([[( 0.,   0.), (42., -42.), ( 0.,   0.), ( 0.,   0.), ( 0.,   0.)],
       [( 0.,   0.), (42., -42.), ( 0.,   0.), ( 0.,   0.), ( 0.,   0.)],
       [( 0.,   0.), (42., -42.), ( 0.,   0.), ( 0.,   0.), ( 0.,   0.)]],
       dtype=[(('x', 's0'), '<f4'), (('y', 's1'), '<f4')])
```

which is nice. However I would also like to assign an array of size 2 to a float2, yet this fails.

```
a[:,1] = np.array((42,-42))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (3)
```

and I have to resort to doing this

```
a[:,1]['x'] = 42
a[:,1]['y'] = -42
```

which works, but kind of defeats the purpose of the whole thing.

Am I missing some obvious syntactic difference or is this feature just not supposed to be used this way?

**EDIT:** In my attempt to present the most minimal example I oversimplified the problem. hpaulj's answer is correct in that if I use explicit dtype=float2 on something of shape=(2,) it will get converted to a shape=(1,) of dtype=float2.
My actual question however was more general, on how to go from say an array(shape=(foo, bar, N), dtype=np.float32) into an array(shape=(foo, bar), dtype=cltp.floatN) with N=2,3,4.

Followup question that just occurred: will an actual copy necessarily occur or can this be converted 'in place'? The actual memory layout looks compatible at first glance.

Comment: The `structured arrays` doc page points to a `recfunctions` package.  In that there's a `unstructured_to_structured` function.  Many of `recfunctions` work by copying values field by field.  Alternatively data is provided to a structured dtype as a list(s) of tuples, just as the array is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [99]: a=np.array([[(0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.)],
    ...:        [(0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.)],
    ...:        [(0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.)]],
    ...:        dtype=[(('x', 's0'), '<f4'), (('y', 's1'), '<f4')])
In [100]: a.dtype
Out[100]: dtype([(('x', 's0'), '<f4'), (('y', 's1'), '<f4')])
In [101]: a.dtype.fields
Out[101]: 
mappingproxy({'s0': (dtype('float32'), 0, 'x'),
              'x': (dtype('float32'), 0, 'x'),
              's1': (dtype('float32'), 4, 'y'),
              'y': (dtype('float32'), 4, 'y')})
```

Look at the intended target, a 3 element array with the compound dtype:

```
In [102]: a[:,1]
Out[102]: 
array([(0., 0.), (0., 0.), (0., 0.)],
      dtype=[(('x', 's0'), '<f4'), (('y', 's1'), '<f4')])
```

While your array is 2 element int.  With this construct the use of tuple doesn't change anything.

```
In [103]: np.array((42,-42))
Out[103]: array([ 42, -42])
```

But if we specify the correct dtype, we make a 0d array:

```
In [104]: np.array((42,-42), a.dtype)
Out[104]: array((42., -42.), dtype=[(('x', 's0'), '<f4'), (('y', 's1'), '<f4')])
```

Now there's no problem assigning it.

```
In [105]: a[:,1] = np.array((42,-42), a.dtype)
```

### edit

```
In [3]: dt = a.dtype
In [4]: dt
Out[4]: dtype([(('x', 's0'), '<f4'), (('y', 's1'), '<f4')])
```

Using a recent `recfunctions` addition, we can make a structured array from an appropriately shape unstructured array:

```
In [5]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
```

2d to 1d structured:

```
In [7]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(np.arange(1,7).reshape(3,2), dtype=dt)
Out[7]: 
array([(1., 2.), (3., 4.), (5., 6.)],
      dtype=[(('x', 's0'), '<f4'), (('y', 's1'), '<f4')])
```

3d to 2d structured:

```
In [8]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2), dtype=dt)
Out[8]: 
array([[( 0.,  1.), ( 2.,  3.), ( 4.,  5.)],
       [( 6.,  7.), ( 8.,  9.), (10., 11.)],
       [(12., 13.), (14., 15.), (16., 17.)],
       [(18., 19.), (20., 21.), (22., 23.)]],
      dtype=[(('x', 's0'), '<f4'), (('y', 's1'), '<f4')])
```

Or making an array from a list of tuples:

```
In [10]: np.array([(0,1),(2,3)], dt)
Out[10]: 
array([(0., 1.), (2., 3.)],
      dtype=[(('x', 's0'), '<f4'), (('y', 's1'), '<f4')])
```

`recfunctions` often makes use of field-by-field setting:

```
In [16]: for name in a.dtype.names:
...:     a[name][:] = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question because I realized I had oversimplified it, apologies for that. Unofortunately this does not work in the more general case, but I appreciate nonetheless.